# How can I ungroup a polars dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, python-polars, iterable-unpacking

I have a polars dataframe that has a particular column with repeating patterns. I have grouped them by the patterns & adding a new column to this grouped dataframe. But now I have to unpack/ungroup this dataframe. How can I do it in polars?

My original dataframe looks like this:

| file | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | cell 1 | cell 2 |
| B | cell 3 | cell 4 |
| A | cell 5 | cell 6 |
| B | cell 7 | cell 8 |

I performed groupby to group the dataframe by FILE & then I added my desired new column & I got below output.

| file | col1 | col2 | folder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | [cell 1, cell 5] | [cell 2, cell 6] | [file1, file2] |
| B | [cell 3, cell 7] | [cell 4, cell 8] | [file1, file2] |

Now I want to ungroup the above dataframe into original format while also including this new column. How can I do it? My actual dataframe is huge & has a lot of rows & columns, using iterations is not effective & quite slow. Is there any function that can be applied to the whole dataframe instead of iterating by columns?

Final desired output:

| file | header 1 | header 2 | folder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | cell 1 | cell 2 | file1 |
| B | cell 3 | cell 4 | file1 |
| A | cell 5 | cell 6 | file2 |
| B | cell 7 | cell 8 | file2 |

I have done the following:

```
dfg = df.groupby('FILE').agg(pl.all())             #to group them first time 
newdf =  dfg.with_columns(pl.repeat([file1,file2,file3], dfg.height)    #adding desired column
```

In what efficient ways can I get the desired output? Note that my dataframe is quite large, so using iterations by column is time consuming.

PS - Updated typo in the final table format. In the column "file" as the entries get repeated after few rows, they should be assigned a new "folder" name.

Comment: What are `file1, file2, file3` in your code?

Comment: If all you want to do is make a column where File A becomes folder file1 and file B becomes folder file2 then just do `dfg.with_columns(folder=pl.col('file').map_dict({'A':'file1', 'B':'file2'})`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to "enumerate" each group.

You can use [`.cum_count()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cum_count.html#polars.Expr.cum_count) for that.

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ file ┆ col1    ┆ col2     │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str      │
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ A    ┆ cell 1  ┆ cell 2   │
│ B    ┆ cell 3  ┆ cell 4   │
│ A    ┆ cell 5  ┆ cell 6   │
│ B    ┆ cell 7  ┆ cell 8   │
│ A    ┆ cell 9  ┆ cell 10  │
│ B    ┆ cell 11 ┆ cell 12  │
│ A    ┆ cell 13 ┆ cell 14  │
│ B    ┆ cell 15 ┆ cell 16  │
│ A    ┆ cell 17 ┆ cell 18  │
│ B    ┆ cell 19 ┆ cell 20  │
└──────┴─────────┴──────────┘
""")
```

```py
df.with_columns(folder = 
   pl.col("file").cum_count().over("file")
)
```

```
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ file ┆ col1    ┆ col2    ┆ folder │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ u32    │
╞══════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ cell 1  ┆ cell 2  ┆ 0      │
│ B    ┆ cell 3  ┆ cell 4  ┆ 0      │
│ A    ┆ cell 5  ┆ cell 6  ┆ 1      │
│ B    ┆ cell 7  ┆ cell 8  ┆ 1      │
│ …    ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …      │
│ A    ┆ cell 13 ┆ cell 14 ┆ 3      │
│ B    ┆ cell 15 ┆ cell 16 ┆ 3      │
│ A    ┆ cell 17 ┆ cell 18 ┆ 4      │
│ B    ┆ cell 19 ┆ cell 20 ┆ 4      │
└──────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

You can turn it into a "repeating sequence" using [modulo arithmetic.](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mod.html)

```py
df.with_columns(folder = 
   pl.col("file").cum_count().over("file").mod(3)
)
```

```
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ file ┆ col1    ┆ col2    ┆ folder │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ u32    │
╞══════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ cell 1  ┆ cell 2  ┆ 0      │
│ B    ┆ cell 3  ┆ cell 4  ┆ 0      │
│ A    ┆ cell 5  ┆ cell 6  ┆ 1      │
│ B    ┆ cell 7  ┆ cell 8  ┆ 1      │
│ …    ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …      │
│ A    ┆ cell 13 ┆ cell 14 ┆ 0      │
│ B    ┆ cell 15 ┆ cell 16 ┆ 0      │
│ A    ┆ cell 17 ┆ cell 18 ┆ 1      │
│ B    ┆ cell 19 ┆ cell 20 ┆ 1      │
└──────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

You can then [`.format()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.format.html#polars.format) the string.

```py
df.with_columns(folder = 
   pl.format("file{}", pl.col("file").cum_count().over("file").mod(3) + 1)
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ file ┆ col1    ┆ col2    ┆ folder │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str    │
╞══════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ cell 1  ┆ cell 2  ┆ file1  │
│ B    ┆ cell 3  ┆ cell 4  ┆ file1  │
│ A    ┆ cell 5  ┆ cell 6  ┆ file2  │
│ B    ┆ cell 7  ┆ cell 8  ┆ file2  │
│ …    ┆ …       ┆ …       ┆ …      │
│ A    ┆ cell 13 ┆ cell 14 ┆ file1  │
│ B    ┆ cell 15 ┆ cell 16 ┆ file1  │
│ A    ┆ cell 17 ┆ cell 18 ┆ file2  │
│ B    ┆ cell 19 ┆ cell 20 ┆ file2  │
└──────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: An alternative to map_dict is `df.with_columns(folder = 
   pl.lit("file") + (1+pl.col("file").cumcount().over("file")).cast(pl.Utf8)
)`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode):

```py
dfg.explode(pl.exclude('file'))
```

Your problem overall might be best solved by a `join` or some type of `over` expression, though:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'file': ['A', 'B'] * 2,
        'col1': [f'cell {i}' for i in range(1, 9, 2)],
        'col2': [f'cell {i}' for i in range(2, 9, 2)],
    }
)
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'file': ['A', 'B'], 'folder': ['file1', 'file2']})

df.join(df2, on='file')
```

```py
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ file ┆ col1   ┆ col2   ┆ folder │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ str    ┆ str    │
╞══════╪════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ cell 1 ┆ cell 2 ┆ file1  │
│ B    ┆ cell 3 ┆ cell 4 ┆ file2  │
│ A    ┆ cell 5 ┆ cell 6 ┆ file1  │
│ B    ┆ cell 7 ┆ cell 8 ┆ file2  │
└──────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apologies from my side, there was a typo in the desired table format which I want. I have edited my question description. 
Basically, what I want is the first 2 rows of file A & B should belong to folder file1 & the last 2 rows of file A & B should belong to folder file2. Meaning, as the column "file" repeats its entries at a certain point, we should assign a new folder name to it. Please see the updated table in my question description above.